# Why does String.getBytes() behave differently in a compiled jar?

Tags: java, encoding

I have a project which reads data from a plaintext file encoded in latin1 and then sends it to a MySQL DB with UTF-8 encoding. 
In some legacy code from an earlier version, the already correctly read strings from the file were re-encoded manually using `new String(String.getBytes("UTF-8"))`. This worked fine in Eclipse, but for some reason, after compiling it to an executable .jar, this caused the Strings to instead be sent in latin1 encoding despite explicitly defining the JDBC as UTF-8 encoded.
After removing the unnecessary conversion, it worked correctly both in the IDE and the compiled jar.

I would like to know what could possibly cause this. The jar and IDE were executed on the same system, and unless Eclipse adds some settings I do not know about the VM-settings were identical. This behavior was also visible on other machines in exactly the same manner.

Comment: Did you try retrieving directly the `Charset` or verifying `Charset.isSupported("UTF-8")`?

Comment: @Jack Can this really be an issue when the strings are still correct apart from nonstandard characters in the output? There were also no exceptions in IDE or .jar related to this. I simply used `getBytes("UTF-8")` exactly like that and included exception handling for `UnsupportedEncodingExceptions`.

Comment: All Java implementations are required to support UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

```
new String(String.getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

Takes the default system encoding for creating the new String. You should always explicitly specify the encoding for the new string, for example

```
new String(String.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")
```

Most likely the default encoding on the other system is different, leading to character set conversions (eg from UTF-8 to Cp1252).

The conversion you apply is only relevant if the string was incorrectly read and if the target character set is different than the source character set. For example: you originally read some bytes as Cp1252, however you then need to convert it to another character set (say as Cp1250). Then you would do:

```
new String(String.getBytes("Cp1252"), "Cp1250")
```

This will convert the characters in the string to bytes in Cp1252, then take the bytes and interprets them in Cp1250. For some (but not all) characters this will map to the same characters, but others will be remapped.

If the string was already correctly read as you imply in your question, then doing this is utterly senseless. Internally a string in Java is simply an array of characters, only when persisting as byte data (or reading from byte data) is the encoding relevant.

Comment: This is a pretty good explanation of the issue :) I can only assume that conversion was necessary at some point in the past and was simply left in as the code evolved before I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
new String(String.getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

doesn't achieve any kind of re-encoding. What it does is turn a string into a byte array, encoding with UTF-8, and then constructs a new string from that, using the *default* encoding. The result is again a String,  and strings in Java have no associated encoding: by specification they contain `char`s, which are UTF-16 codepoints. There is no byte-level encoding defined. The *best* that line of code can do is retrieve the exact same string, and if the default encoding doesn't match, the result will be a broken string.

If you have issues with the wrong encoding used towards the database, you must act on the JDBC level, ensuring that Strings sent over the wire are properly encoded.